# How to add a image class "img-fluid" into the img tag in the Trumbowyg editor

Tags: javascript, css, trumbowyg

I want to add a bootstrap image class `img-fluid` into the img tag in the Trumbowyg text editor.

I tried the `tagClasses: {img: 'img-fluid'},` I added the bootstrap5 cdn link into my code file but it is not working , I also check their documentation and github also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.